# Question on critical groups

Tags: algebraic-topology

I have this theoreme with it's proof

[image]

But i don't understand who is $f_0$ ?

Can someone help me please ?

Thank you .

Comment: That's either a typo, a huge ommision...or $\,f_0\,$ was defined before somewhere. What books is that from?

Comment: is Infinite Dimensional Morse Theory by K.C.Chang

Comment: in the notation index there is $f_a$ is level set of f, not above the level a , so $f_0$ is the level set of $f$ not above the level 0 ?

Comment: In page 310 the notation $\,f_a\,$ is explained as the level set of $\,f\,$ not above the level $\,a\,$ ...I'm not sure what this means, and in page 20, where it refers, I couldn't find anything, so either my vision sucks or this is a rather sloppy feature in that book.

Comment: thank you, i think that i understand the meaning